How to fix "Syntax error, unrecognized expression" when using custom commands in Cypress?
I was learning cypress from
https://learn.cypress.io/testing-your-first-application/how-to-test-forms-and-custom-cypress-commands
And, i did the same for creating custom commands but i am getting this error when running the test.
Please see the attachments below:
[image1](https://i.sstatic.net/6FLu0.png)
[image2](https://i.sstatic.net/oLzvd.png)
[image3](https://i.sstatic.net/xpuON.png)

In the commands.ts file, i inserted
declare namespace Cypress {
interface Chainable {
getByData(dataTestAttribute: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>
}
}

Cypress.Commands.add("getByData", (selector) => {
return cy.get('[data-test=${selector}]')
})

And then, in the home.cy.ts file, I used this
describe('home page', () => {
beforeEach(() =>{
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
})

it('the h1 contains the correct text', () => {
cy.getByData('hero-heading').contains('Testing Next.js Applications with Cypress')
})

it("the features on the homepage are correct",() =>{
cy.get("dt").eq(0).contains("4 Courses")
cy.get("dt").eq(1).contains("25+ Lessons")
cy.get("dt").eq(2).contains("Free and Open Source")
})
})

I expect the test to be run without any error
But, I am getting this error:
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-test=${selector}]

